# checking if a user scrolls to top or bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to figure out a way to detect whether a UIScrollView is scrolled to the top or the bottom. I know I will have to do some calculation using the contentOffset.y, but how do I do the calculation?

Comment: Add NSLog to your scroll delegate, scroll up and down, and see what you get. You should see zero on one side, and (totalSize-windowSize) on the other end.

Answer (score 2):

The `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` method of UIScrollViewDelegate is probably a good place to start looking. The `targetContentOffset` will be a CGPoint that will contain the offset of where the scrollview will finish. `targetContentOffset.y` will be 0 when scrolling to the top and `scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height` when scrolling to the bottom.